# How do I type umlauts and other special characters with Swype?

Tags: keyboard, swype, localization, special-chars

I can change the swype-interpreting language, but the keyboard doesn't show me any special symbols.

HTC Incredible with Swype 2.4.44.10912.t100 (have not updated to Dec beta, yet).

I just want to swipe "Blue Öyster Cult" -- is that so wrong?

Comment: tag-soup. Not sure where to go with this one

Comment: This question needs more cowbell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press and hold the 'o' key.  At first you'll get a pop-up showing the left parenthesis.  Hold it longer and you'll get another popup showing accents for the character.

Comment: And once you've entered the word once with the accent in it, next time you can just swipe through and it'll add the accent automatically (or offer the accented word as one of the popup alternatives) without needing to long-press on anything again.

Comment: Durrr! I remember this from the stock keyboard app, but I didn't know it was available in Swype... I'm so used to just swooshing my fingertip around...

Comment: I hadn't tried it yet so I had to open a new message and check.  BTW, please mark this as the answer, thanks.